# Adsense served ads not changing inside react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-tag-manager, adsense

I'm having an issue with my adsense ad inside my react component, it will almost always display the same ad on route change. I suspect this is because Google sees the route as an empty page and so would not serve personalized ads.

What I currently have is very simple. I have the google script on my index.html
and then my ad component which I'm calling under my App component.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Ad extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }

render () {
    return (
      <div className='ad'>
        <ins className='adsbygoogle'
          style={{ display: 'block' }}
          data-ad-client='ca-pub-4543556906953539'
          data-ad-slot='3566322911'
          data-ad-format='auto'
          data-full-width-responsive="true"
           />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I was reading this thread and the answer was use googletags to manage served ads:
[Using google adsense with React + React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922455/using-google-adsense-with-react-react-router)

However I found the answer vague maybe because I have never used google tag manager nor ads manager before. Does anyone have more information on this?